# how to use web browser control of .net?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

i am using winforms in .net. I am trying to create a html page in web browser control using c++. I am getting error when i do this

webBrowser1->Document = "hi";

how to create a html page and display it using web browser control?

Comment: What error? Always include the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

`webBrowser1->Document` expects an [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx), but you gave it a string. Also, the [`Document` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) is read-only (no setter defined), so it cannot be set.

Try this instead:

```
webBrowser1->DocumentText = "<html><body>hi</body></html>";
```

Notice that this uses the `DocumentText` property instead of the `Document` property.